# MySql Error connecting to database: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

I have two domain names through the same hosting provider. I am testing my php scripts on one of the domains before moving them over to the 'live' website I'm currently building. This worked for me very well yesterday as I developed some scripts. Today, I ran into the strangest of problems...

Using my test website, I am having no problems whatsoever adding an email address to a MySql database. However, when I try the exact same thing using the exact same files on the other site, I get the error message that I titled this post with:

Error connecting to database: No such file or directory

I'm literally looking at the two sites side by side in different browser tabs and clicking the submit button with a successful response from one site and the error message from the other.

Can anyone figure out what the problem might be?

Thanks!

The code to connect:

```
// Database connection constants
define("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost");
define("DATABASE_USERNAME", ********);
define("DATABASE_PASSWORD", ********);
define("DATABASE_NAME", ********);
```

I've replaced sensitive information with ******** but the actual files have the proper strings in them.

Comment: Can you show the code used to connect to the database, and the line that causes the error you reported?

Comment: obviously they're not "the exact same files". you might have copied html/css/images, but missed something else, like a .htaccess or hard-coded .conf stuff. or you overwrote something you shouldn't have, and have now pointed to a directory (e.g. mysql socket file location) that doesn't match what's on the old server.

Comment: They are the same files. Same date and time stamp. Same contents.

Comment: click **EDIT** below the question to updaed it with relevant information.

Comment: Marc B - I'm not sure what you mean. I am editing the files on my own computer, then uploading them to the correct directories individually via FTP. I am not copy/pasting from one to the other

Comment: Here is my process:

Comment: 1. Create php file on my computer, 2. Upload to test website via FTP, 3. Test on that site, 4. Upload to live website via FTP

Comment: Can you confirm if both domains have the same virtual machine, same configuration files, same access permissions as well as post the error received when the PHP fails (if you can also post the error.log, that would aid, with the script line as well).

Comment: Bonatti - I don't know for sure about virtual machine, config, access etc. but both sites are through the same hosting company so it would be a surprise to learn that those details are different. How do I find that out? I have an error log but it doesn't seem to contain any info about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Problem solved. Thank you to all who helped out! I called my hosting provider and they cleared up the issue for me. Apparently each of the two websites has its own hosting account and therefore, I had to create a new MySQL account for the second website.